# cocos2d-js pass sprite object into EventListener

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js

I am using cocos2d-js v3.0 and I am trying to use the this.sprite object in the EventListener. However I get that the this.sprite is undefined.

If I create the var sprite in the init function and just pass sprite it works fine. But when I create the var sprite outside the init function and use this.sprite I get the undefined.

```
var roomMap = cc.Layer.extend({

sprite:null


ctor:function(){
    this._super();
    this.init();
},

init: function () {
    this._super();
    //create tile map
    this.mainMap = cc.TMXTiledMap.create(res.Main_tmx);

    var cache = cc.spriteFrameCache;
    cache.addSpriteFrames(res.player_plist, res.player_png);

    this.sprite = new cc.Sprite.create("#player-stand-f-0");
    this.sprite.setPosition(new cc.Point(300,300));
    this.addChild(this.sprite);

    var listener = cc.EventListener.create({

        event: cc.EventListener.MOUSE,

        onMouseUp: function (event){
            var sprite_action = cc.MoveTo(2,cc.p(event.getLocationX(),event.getLocationY()));
            console.log(this.sprite);
            //this.sprite.runAction(sprite_action);
            //this.addChild(sprite_action);

        }
    });

    cc.eventManager.addListener(listener, this.sprite);
```

This is more a javascript problem I am having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's happening because `this`, inside the event listener, is referring to the event listener itself, and not the layer.

Try this:

```
var target = event.getCurrentTarget();
console.log(target);
console.log(target.sprite);
```

This should give you a clear idea of what's going on: if you are clicking the sprite object, then `target` should equal to `sprite` (and hence `target.sprite` will be undefined), if you are clicking the layer, then `target` will be the layer, and `target.sprite` will be what you expected.

I reccomend taking a look at [this article](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/new-event-manager-in-cocos2d-html5-v3-0/11637) for further understanding of the new event manager in cocos2d v3.

Comment: thank you for the article. Yes target now has the layer object.

Answer (score -1):

first, i think this line is wrong

```
this.sprite = new cc.Sprite.create("#player-stand-f-0");
```

"new" is unnecessary

when you said "outside the init function", i don't know where it is.
because the ctor function will be called first, once you didn't create it before using, it will be undefined. you can try

```
sprite:cc.Sprite.create("player-stand-f-0")
```